# On Minecraft when i load it it closes and says Error installing VM? How do i fix this

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

when I load Minecraft it says:
[image]

How do I fix this? I tried to reinstall it but it didn't help

Comment: You probably didn't allocate enough memory. How much RAM do you have installed?

Comment: It is either because too little allocated RAM, which can only be if you have a real old pc or some mods installed, or you might have the 'wrong' Java installed (32-bit instead of 64-bit)

Comment: its my friend who is having the problem. she has a new laptop but everything lags on it so i think it has low storage. she tried to get java again already

Answer (score 0):

You should download the Jar version of the MC launcher, and if it can't open, you should download Java too.

(Choose the [Jar version here](https://minecraft.net/en/download/alternative), there it says it is for Linux, but works on all OSes. Won't work? Download [JRE](https://java.com/en/download/))